# Uniform distribution problems

Tags: distributions, self-study, uniform-distribution

I was confused about this problem

Two emergency response units， unit A and unit B， patrol uniformly and independent a 10-km stretch of moad. An emergency incident occurs on the road and its position is uniformly distributed， independent of the positions of the response units. The incident requires both response units to be dispatched to the scene. Assume that reaponse speed is fixed at km per hour and U-turns are permitted.
 （1）Determine the mean travel time for unit A to reach the scene. 
 （2）Determine the mean time unit the first unit （either A or B） reaches the scene.
 （3）Determine the pdf for the time until the second unit reaches the scene.

I quite can't understand any of them  ,the only thing l seem to know is that three of them are all uniform distributed between zero to ten....

Comment: I can understand why this problem statement is troublesome: it poses a physically ridiculous model of patrolling, right at the outset--units cannot just disappear and reappear "uniformly and independent[ly]." Therefore you will need to use some common sense and creativity to guess what the questioner might be trying to get at.  If your answer is being evaluated (by a teacher or examiner), your best defense is to make your interpretation and assumptions as clear as possible to them.

Comment: You can rewrite your question as $A,B,C$ are i.i.d. random variables uniformly on $[0,10]$. For given $s \gt 0$, what are (1) $E[|A-C|/s]$ and (2) $E[\min(|A-C|/s, |B-C|/s)]$ and (3) the density of $\max(|A-C|/s, |B-C|/s)$ ?